# How can a Microsoft Exchange server be configured to redirect SMTP mail to another email address?

Tags: exchange

I'm looking for a method of selectively intercepting and redirecting SMTP email on an existing, hosted Microsoft Exchange server in production, with the following constraints:

- The Exchange server handles email for several foobar.com email accounts
- When bill@foobar.com sends an email to barbara@contoso.com (a third party with its own email service provider), the Exchange server should not deliver the email to barbara@contoso.com, but instead send the email to dump@foobar.com
- When bill@foobar.com sends an email to any email address other than barbara@contoso.com, SMTP relay occurs successfully without redirection
- The redirection must be configured on the server itself, rather than on bill@foobar.com's email client

Answer (score 0):

Many of the rules that are configured via Outlook run on the server.  Connect to the server as the user to be forwarded, and add the appropriate forwarding rules.

It may be possible for administrators to define the rules without logging in as the user.